# What are the commands that firefox and google chrome print html files to pdf?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, pdf, printing

In either Firefox or Google Chrome On Ubuntu 14.04, I can hit Ctrl+P and choose "Print to file" to print the current html webpage to a pdf.

Are the browsers  using some printing commands outside of them to do that?

What are the corresponding commands that run in terminal and do the same? Thanks.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome both can handle PDF files natively this means they can print to a PDF using that capability.  How exactly beyond that statement is going outside of the scope of this website.